# 301 Redirect dynamic page with htaccess with known variables

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a relatively straight forward task, but one which I help with so I don't mess up the whole SEO.

I have a current set of products which are assigned a category: `/products/internal/$1` - `$1` being any individual product.

However, what I need to do is actually 301 redirect everything to /product/ with the "s", so:
`/products/internal/$1` to `/product/internal/$1`

As ever, I've read a few other threads, but unsure what applies if you know the being structure of the URL.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because URL rewriting is an already broadly discussed topic, but this show no own efforts whatsoever.

Comment: Your opinion obviously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RedirectMatch 301 /products/internal/(.*) /product/internal/$1
```

Comment: Thanks. I shall put this into action and see if it solves my issue and mark it accordingly.